# Checking children for tags in Beautiful Soup 4 with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup 4 with python to parse through some HTML.  Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html_doc = '<p class="line-spacing-double" align="center">IN <i>THE </i><b>DISTRICT</b> COURT OF {county} COUNTY\nSTATE OF OKLAHOMA</p>'

soup = bs(html_doc, 'html.parser')
para = soup.p

for child in soup.p.children:
    print (child)
```

The result is:

```
IN
<i>THE </i>
<b>DISTRICT</b>
 COURT OF {county} COUNTY
STATE OF OKLAHOMA
```

This all makes sense.  What I'm trying to do is iterate through the results and if I find a `<i>` or `<b>` then do something different with them.  When I try the following, it doesn't work:

```
for child in soup.p.children:
    if child.findChildren('i'):
        print('italics found')
```

The error is because the first returned child is a string and I'm trying to search it for a child tag and BS4 already knows there are no children present.

So I changed up the code to check if the child is a string, and if so, do not attempt to take any action on it, just print it out.

```
for child in soup.p.children:
    if isinstance(child, str):
        print(child)
    elif child.findAll('i'):
        for tag in child.findAll('i'):
            print(tag)
```

The result of this latest code:

```
IN
 COURT OF {county} COUNTY
STATE OF OKLAHOMA
```

As I loop through the results, I need to be able to check for tags in the result, but I can't seem to figure out how.  I thought it should be simple, but I'm stumped.

EDIT:

In response to jacalvo:

If I run

```
for child in soup.p.children:
    if child.find('i'):
        print(child)
```

It still fails to print out the 2nd and 3rd lines from the HTML code

Edit:

```
for child in soup.p.children:
    if isinstance(child, str):
        print(child)
    else:
        print(child.findChildren('i', recursive=False))
```

This resulted in:

```
IN
[]
[]
 COURT OF {county} COUNTY
STATE OF OKLAHOMA
```

Comment: What about using `find('i')` instead of findChildren()?

Comment: `p = soup.select_one('p')` and then `p.select('i, b')`

Comment: jacalvo - I needed to write code (which sucks in comments) so I responded to you through an edit in the original post.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely - That works for finding the `<i>` and `<b>` tags, but I do need to loop through all of them, not just find those tags.  Their placement within the HTML matters for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an example what your are trying to do as an example of "do something different" with tags?  Having a sample of the full desired output in the question would help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html_doc = '<p class="line-spacing-double" align="center">IN <i>THE</i> <b>DISTRICT</b> COURT OF {county} COUNTY\nSTATE OF OKLAHOMA</p>'
soup = bs(html_doc, 'html.parser')
para = soup.p

for child in para.children:
    if child.name == 'i':
        print(f'*{child.text}*',end='')
    elif child.name == 'b':
        print(f'**{child.text}**',end='')
    else:
        print(child,end='')
```

Output:

```
IN *THE* **DISTRICT** COURT OF {county} COUNTY
STATE OF OKLAHOMA
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I wasn't even thinking about the name of the child being the tag present, but that makes perfect sense in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    html_doc = '<p class="line-spacing-double" align="center">IN <i>THE </i><b>DISTRICT</b> COURT OF {county} ' \
               'COUNTY\nSTATE OF OKLAHOMA</p> '

    soup = bs(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    paragraph = soup.p

    # all tags dynamically gotten
    tags = [tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()]

    for child in paragraph.children:
        if child.name in tags:
            print('{0}'.format(child))  # or child.text
        else:
            print(child)
```

Output

```
    IN 
    <i>THE </i>
    <b>DISTRICT</b>
     COURT OF {county} COUNTY
    STATE OF OKLAHOMA
```

Comment: I'm going to respond to you by editing the question so I can post the code I ran with your `recursive=False` in it.

Comment: I'm about to resort to regex :)  The greatest sin for HTML parsing LOL

Comment: OMG! that's an extreme decision to make... (: maybe I don't get your idea, but I updated the code with more italics and bolds and printed them all in two different lists so you can do further manipulation afterwards

Comment: This finds all of the italics and bold, but it doesn't let me iterate through the text as children. 

The reason I need to iterate through them, is that I'm converting to DOCX and I need to use python-docx to add_run() and that requires a certain order compared to the other text that is also in the paragraph.

Comment: Oh! I had a similar issue when I made a huge dynamic rich text with worksheet.write_rich_string in xlsxwriter... the order matters. so, you need children, tags and text while doing the process, I guess

Comment: I added tag.name and child.text to keep both elements. let's see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Use `findChildren`() and then check the child name with if conditions.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html_doc = '<p class="line-spacing-double" align="center">IN <i>THE </i><b>DISTRICT</b> COURT OF {county} COUNTY\nSTATE OF OKLAHOMA</p>'

soup = bs(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for child in soup.find('p').findChildren(recursive=False) :
    if child.name=='i':
        print(child)
    if child.name=='b':
        print(child)
```

### Output:

```
<i>THE </i>
<b>DISTRICT</b>
```